Reading the 32 Fifo samples from MAX30102 for a 100 samples buffer
I'm using the max30102 sensor and esp32. I'm programming using arduino firmware.
The sensor has a FIFO with 32 samples and I want to read them for a buffer with size of 100 samples.
So I need to read that FIFO 4 times.
Maxim has available a firmware but reads 1 sample from FIFO each time, here is the function:
bool maxim_max30102_read_fifo(uint32_t *pun_red_led, uint32_t *pun_ir_led)
//#endif
/**
* brief        Read a set of samples from the MAX30102 FIFO register
* par          Details
*               This function reads a set of samples from the MAX30102 FIFO register
*
* param[out]   *pun_red_led   - pointer that stores the red LED reading data
* param[out]   *pun_ir_led    - pointer that stores the IR LED reading data
*
* retval       true on success
*/
{
  uint32_t un_temp;
  uint8_t uch_temp;
  *pun_ir_led=0;
  *pun_red_led=0;
  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_1, &uch_temp);
  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_2, &uch_temp);
  Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_WRITE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(REG_FIFO_DATA);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(I2C_READ_ADDR,6);

  un_temp=Wire.read();
  un_temp<<=16;
  *pun_red_led+=un_temp;
  un_temp=Wire.read();
  un_temp<<=8;
  *pun_red_led+=un_temp;
  un_temp=Wire.read();
  *pun_red_led+=un_temp;

  un_temp=Wire.read();
  un_temp<<=16;
  *pun_ir_led=un_temp;
  un_temp=Wire.read();
  un_temp<<=8;
  *pun_ir_led+=un_temp;
  un_temp=Wire.read();
  *pun_ir_led+=un_temp;

  *pun_red_led&=0x03FFFF;  //Mask MSB [23:18]
  *pun_ir_led&=0x03FFFF;  //Mask MSB [23:18]

  return true;
}

and out of this function, in the main code, there is a loop for execute this function 100x (size of buffer)
how can I change that function to read 32 samples instead of 1 and how should I call it in the loop to execute it the times I need?
I tried this:
bool maxim_max30102_read_fifo(uint32_t *pun_red_led, uint32_t *pun_ir_led, uint8_t samples_to_read)
//#endif
/**
* brief        Read a set of samples from the MAX30102 FIFO register
* par          Details
*               This function reads a set of samples from the MAX30102 FIFO register
*
* param[out]   *pun_red_led   - pointer that stores the red LED reading data
* param[out]   *pun_ir_led    - pointer that stores the IR LED reading data
*
* retval       true on success
*/
{
  uint8_t i;
  uint32_t un_temp;
  uint8_t uch_temp, ptr_temp;
  *pun_ir_led=0;
  *pun_red_led=0;

  // First transaction: Get the FIFO_WR_PTR
  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_FIFO_WR_PTR, &uch_temp);
  uint8_t fifo_wr_ptr = uch_temp;
  
  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_FIFO_RD_PTR, &uch_temp);
  uint8_t fifo_rd_ptr = uch_temp;


  // Evaluate number of samples available, handling wraparound
  uint8_t num_available_samples;
  if (fifo_wr_ptr >= fifo_rd_ptr) {
    num_available_samples = fifo_wr_ptr - fifo_rd_ptr + 1;
  } else {
    num_available_samples = fifo_wr_ptr + FIFO_DEPTH - fifo_rd_ptr + 1;
    }
  // Determine the actual number of samples to read
  samples_to_read = min( num_available_samples, samples_to_read);

  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_1, &uch_temp);
  maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_2, &uch_temp);
  Wire.beginTransmission(I2C_WRITE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(REG_FIFO_DATA);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(I2C_READ_ADDR,samples_to_read*6);

  for (i = 0; i < samples_to_read; i++) {
    // Read LED1 data
        un_temp = Wire.read();
        un_temp <<= 16;
        *pun_red_led += un_temp;

        un_temp = Wire.read();
        un_temp <<= 8;
        *pun_red_led += un_temp;

        un_temp = Wire.read();
        *pun_red_led += un_temp;

        // Read LED2 data
        un_temp = Wire.read();
        un_temp <<= 16;
        *pun_ir_led += un_temp;

        un_temp = Wire.read();
        un_temp <<= 8;
        *pun_ir_led += un_temp;

        un_temp = Wire.read();
        *pun_ir_led += un_temp;

        *pun_red_led&=0x03FFFF;  //Mask MSB [23:18]
        *pun_ir_led&=0x03FFFF;  //Mask MSB [23:18]

  }
  return true;
}

and out of the function I call it this way:
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
uint32_t aun_ir_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t aun_red_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];  //red LED sensor data

for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i += NUM_SAMPLES_PER_READ) {
  while (digitalRead(oxiInt) == 1); // Wait until the interrupt pin asserts

 // Calculate the number of samples to read in this iteration
  uint8_t samples_to_read = min(NUM_SAMPLES_PER_READ, BUFFER_SIZE - i);

  maxim_max30102_read_fifo((aun_red_buffer + i ), (aun_ir_buffer + i ), samples_to_read);
  // Print the data
  for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SAMPLES_PER_READ; j++) {
    Serial.print(i + j, DEC);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(aun_red_buffer[i + j], DEC);
    Serial.print(F("\t"));
    Serial.print(aun_ir_buffer[i + j], DEC);    
    Serial.println("");
  }
}

But I'm having troubles because I'm trying to access non-existent places of arrays, or there is no data read.
The fifo it increments automatically its read pointer after 1byte read.

You're not going to fit four reads of 32 samples into a 100 sample array, the math just doesn't work. 4 * 32 == 128, so at the least your array needs to hold 128 samples. You said you're trying to access non-existent places in the arrays but you didn't actually include the code that defines the arrays. Please edit the question to include a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the problem and includes all the relevant code.

I've edited to includ more relevant code now @romkey
